# Detect at runtime if a load is atomic?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, memory-fences

My application requires a couple of atomic loads and stores. Unfortunately, these operations must occur at a particular address in a memory mapped file and so I cannot use c++11's std::atomic (since std::atomic works by controlling the size and alignment/placement of the variable. Since I control the memory mapped file format and we only run on a single CPU architecture I simply looked up the alignment and size constraints of my target and arranged things to allow for the atomicity (including a full fence at just the right spot).

Is there a way to test (at runtime) if a read or a write of a particular size to a particular address would be atomic? My primary platform is x86-64 but I'd also be interested in solutions for ARM.

Comment: Good point. Added platform information.

Comment: Unless you're using architecture-specific instructions, your loads/stores generally aren't going to be atomic (atomic instructions are slower than nonatomic instructions, so compilers will emit nonatomic instructions unless you explicitly say not to). ARM has a very weak memory model too (weaker than x86's), so you're certainly getting into architecture specific territory, and this is an area you don't want to cross your fingers and hope the compiler psychically knows what you want. You'd have to look at the actual assembly for that load/store to know if it's atomic or not.

Comment: (continued) If you want atomic loads/stores, you should use the proper assembly instructions (or compiler intrinsics). Out of curiosity, why do you want to test this at runtime? This is the kind of thing you should know before the code is even compiled, IMO.

Comment: The reason I am looking for this is that I'd like to add a check at startup for the required functionality and fail fast if its not present... In general, we control the hardware we run on, but I'd like to add a sanity check anyway...

Comment: @dicroce you could write a function that executes all the desired atomic assembly instructions. If it generates an illegal opcode/instruction, then you know the hardware doesn't support it (and you'll fail, because the processor will trap). If it succeeds with no errors, you're good. Execute the function at program startup as a test. But all x86_64 architectures support some atomic instructions, so I doubt you'll have a CPU on which the program won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Probably not. You could write some code that updates and checks validity of your values, and run that for 6 months. However, it will almost certainly not GUARANTEE that the code is correct - just that you haven't hit the right spot to make it go wrong.

Long answer: Loads and stores of processor words are almost certainly atomic in and of themselves, however the `std::atomic` functionality provides a stronger guarantee than that. It guarantees that no processor will use a value that is "stale" (cache-coherency and exclusive updates). You can't make the same guarantee without `std::atomic` (unless the platform itself guarantees this, which would probably require it to be a single core processor at the very least).

In a generic case, loads and stores as performed by the processor has a "weak" cache coherency and atomic update policy. Say we have this code:

```
 int a = 42; 
 bool flag = false;

 ... 

 a++;
 flag = true;
```

and some other code that does:

```
 while(!flag)
 a--;
```

[I'm currently ignoring the fact that `flag` also needs atomic update policy and probably needs to be volatile - that is not the point in this case]

There is no guarantee that the compiler doesn't form `tmp = a; tmp = tmp+1; a = tmp;` (and corresponding for the `a--`) [possibly with extra instructions thrown in between for good measure, because the compiler expects that to be faster/better in some other way].

There is also no guarantee that the value won't have been updated to `43`, but the other code has read the old `42` value after it exits the loop because `flag` is true (because the processor is not doing everything in exactly the order you expect, and the cache-content is updated "out of order").

x86-processors are definitely among the ones that have not got guarantees that the updated value will be immediately available as described above. Cache coherency and atomicity just guarantees that you won't read some "half-baked" value - it's either the "old" or the "new" value when updating a value - but it may be the "old" value for quite some time after the "new" value has been written, which is typically "not a good thing".

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I also used a memory fence in the required place so cache coherency isn't really a concern... i was mostly just curious if it would be possible to perform some test at startup so I can fail fast if the required atomicity isn't present...

Comment: Not really, at least as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Assuming the range of functionality you actually need is fairly limited, I'd probably go for writing some assembler code to perform atomic (using `lock` as appropriate) - or intrinsics, or manage to make `std::atomic` do what you want.

Comment: Note also that memory fences are only WITHIN the processor, so it has no relation to other processor(core)s in the system. That is where atomic instructioins are required.